# Image doesn't show up at canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to do a simple Python Canvas. But when I try to do the PhotoImage thing to display it on canvas. it just doesn't show up. There is just a blank 500x500. I don't know if i import something wrong or what. The path file is correct, it just shows a blank canvas.

```
from tkinter import *

import time

HEIGHT = 500

WIDTH = 500

window = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(window,height=HEIGHT,width=WIDTH)

canvas.update()

photo_Image = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\figue\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\gatito.png')

my_image = canvas.create_image(0,0,image=photo_Image,anchor=NW)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please do not use `import *`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Tkinter's `.pack()` method on your canvas widget. If you do not the widget won't get added to your window thus you won't see anything.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 500
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window,height=HEIGHT,width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()
photo_Image = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\figue\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\gatito.png')
my_image = canvas.create_image(0,0,image=photo_Image,anchor=NW)
window.mainloop()
```